# C++ inline casting and casting into variable works differently

Tags: c++, gcc, casting

```
class Old
{
    protected:
        long val;
    public:
        long myVal()
        {
            return val;
        }

        void myVal(long val)
        {
            this->val = val;
        }
};

template<typename T> class In: virtual public Old
{
    protected:
        T value;

    public:
        void setValue(T val)
        {
            value = val;
        }

        T getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
};


class My: public In<int>, public In<bool>
{

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    My m;
    m.myVal(100);
    In<int> iv = (In<int>) m;
    std::cout << "start_ils: " << ((In<int>)m).getValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "start_vs: "<< iv.getValue() << std::endl;
    ((In<int>)m).setValue(10);
    std::cout << "=== old's val ===" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "old_vs: "<<iv.myVal() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "old_ilsi: " << ((In<int>)m).myVal() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "old_ilsb: " << ((In<bool>)m).myVal() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "=== set_ils ===" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get_ils: " << ((In<int>)m).getValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get_vs: "<< iv.getValue() << std::endl;
    iv.setValue(10);
    std::cout << "=== set_vs ===" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get_ils: " << ((In<int>)m).getValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get_vs: "<< iv.getValue() << std::endl;
}
```

this code produce this output:

```
start_ils: -2126649320
start_vs: -2126649320
=== old's val ===
old_vs: 100
old_ilsi: 100
old_ilsb: 100
=== set_ils ===
get_ils: -2126649320
get_vs: -2126649320
=== set_vs ===
get_ils: -2126649320
get_vs: 10
```

What works differently, if i cast My to In to access `int getValue()` when I does it inline or first put into a variable?
Looks like it's access bad segment but more strange that if I do inline cast My to In I can't access the right value of In but its correctly access the super type Old's `long val` field (trough methods).

gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

Comment: Please remove the casts.  Do you get compiler errors?  If so, what are the errors?  Are they errors stating that "the types are not compatible" or similar messages?  If so, there is a good reason for it, and casting to shut the compiler up is a sign that things can/will go wrong.

Comment: Yes the first two print is to show there is same junk using the two different cast.
Secound I access the superclass variable Old with 3 different way and works.
Third I set variable with inline cast and values remains same junk at start time.
The last way: works partially, if i access with vi variable.
Beacuse of My class is inherited from In<int> and In<bool> compiles will not know what i want if i call getValue(). Should return int or bool?

Comment: Instead of casting, you can specify the class to refer to using the scope resolution operator.  Here is an example:   http://ideone.com/kC0TSX

Comment: That's what i exactly want, but until this time i don't know how. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code causes undefined behaviour by printing uninitialized variables.  The results of this may be unstable.

To fix this, initialize `val` and `value` before trying to print them.  (Note that with virtual inheritance, only the most-derived constructor should initialize a variable).

You didn't say which parts of your program output you didn't understand. I'm guessing you expected the last two output lines to show the same number.

Perhaps you are unaware that `(In<int>)m` copy-constructs a temporary object from `m`.

The line `((In<int>)m).setValue(10);` creates a temporary object, sets its value to `10`, then destroys the temporary object. It does not affect `m`.

The line `In<int> iv = (In<int>) m;` makes `iv` be a copy of part of `m`. Future changes to `m` would not affect `iv`.  When you write `iv.setValue(10)`, that updates `iv` but not `m`.

If you want to refer to `m` via  base class, use `static_cast<In<int> &>(m)`. The `&` means to form a reference, instead of copying by value. You probably also intended to have `In<int> &iv = m;` instead of `In<int> iv = (In<int>) m;`.

Comment: Really, the default copy constructor caused this 'strange' behaviour what about i completly forget. Thanks :)